# L'Hopital and derivatives of exponential functions

Tags: limits, derivatives

How can I solve the limit when $n$ approaches $\infty$ of:

$f(n) = (n * 2^n) / 3^n$

It seems to me that this is an indeterminate case of $(\infty / \infty)$ so I can apply l´Hopital rule, getting the derivative of both the numerator and denominator. However the result of those derivatives includes $2^n$ and $3^n$ again and again, no matter how many times I get such derivatives. What is a good approach to solve this situation?

Respectfully,

Jorge Maldonado

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try writing it as
$$\frac n{(3/2)^n}.$$

Comment: Great! I appreciate that.